# Cosmos Nested JSON Query

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

This is the fist time that I work with CosmosDB and I am trying to create a Query to get some details about this JSON:

```
{
"Status": "Uploaded",
"ProvidedOn": "2022-04-04T18:34:57.4160484Z",
"DocumentTaxonomy": {
    "JurisdictionalCountriesOfService": [
        {
            "Id": 5,
            "Name": "United States"
        }
    ],
    "WorkProduct": {
        "Id": 762,
        "Name": "Other reports and documents",
        "Type": "Info item"
    }
},
"id": "3a92c052-bc23-4b8a-acbf-54044785968a",
"Meta": {
    "VersionId": "3",
    "LastUpdated": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "Source": null,
    "Security": null,
    "Tag": null,
    "Id": null,
    "Extension": null,
    "ModifierExtension": null
},
```

}

Basicaly I need to get something like

`SELECT  id,Status,ProvidedOn, WorkProductName, WorkProductType,MetaVersionId FROM JSONFILE`

In this image I am highlighting the columnsthat my query needs

NOTE: since I need to query different CosmoDB, not all of them have the DocumentTaxonomy section so the plan is when they doesn't exists return like a null or blank value

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to show the actual query you tried, along with issues you're having. You showed a sample query (which has invalid syntax), so I suspect that's not something you actually tried. Just a bit difficult, as written, to understand the specific issue(s) you're having. Please edit to be more clear about these things (including expected vs actual output, errors, etc)

Comment: SELECT 
    c.id, 
    c.ProvidedOn, 
    c.Status,
    IS_DEFINED(c.DocumentTaxonomy.WorkProduct.Type) TypeDoc,
    IS_DEFINED(c.DocumentTaxonomy.WorkProduct.Name) AS NameDoc
FROM c

Comment: Pablo - you need to *edit your question* - it's very hard to read code and queries in a comment. Also, you need to show what's working, what's not, and what specific issues you need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question, the code should return the DocumentTaxonomy section values if they exist in the JSON otherwise It should return null or blank values.

This code may work for you:

```
SELECT c.id, c.ProvidedOn, c.Status,c.Meta.VersionId as versionId,
IS_DEFINED(c.DocumentTaxonomy.WorkProduct.Type) = true ? c.DocumentTaxonomy.WorkProduct.Type
  : IS_DEFINED(c.DocumentTaxonomy.WorkProduct.Type) = false ? null 
  : "some default value"
  as TypeDoc, 
IS_DEFINED(c.DocumentTaxonomy.WorkProduct.Name) = true ? c.DocumentTaxonomy.WorkProduct.Name
  : IS_DEFINED(c.DocumentTaxonomy.WorkProduct.Name) = false ? null
  : "some default value"
  as NameDoc 
FROM c
```

The Output it gave when DocumentTaxonomy section exists is:

```
[
    {
        "id": "3a92c052-bc23-4b8a-acbf-54044785968a",
        "ProvidedOn": "2022-04-04T18:34:57.4160484Z",
        "Status": "Uploaded",
        "versionId": "3",
        "TypeDoc": "Info item",
        "NameDoc": "Other reports and documents"
    }
]
```

The Output when DocumentTaxonomy section not exists :

```
[
    {
        "id": "3a92c052-bc23-4b8a-acbf-54044785968a",
        "ProvidedOn": "2022-04-04T18:34:57.4160484Z",
        "Status": "Uploaded",
        "versionId": "3",
        "TypeDoc": null,
        "NameDoc": null
    }
]
```

Please check the screenshot of the output for your reference:

[image]